# What does $\dim_k k[V]$ mean

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Explain please what does $\dim_k k[V]$ mean in the following lemma:

Let $V$ be closed subset affine with respect to the Zariski topology of $A^n$. Then $\dim V = 0 \Leftrightarrow V$ is finite. In this case $|V| = \dim_k k[V]$.

Comment: It means the dimension of the $k$-vector space $k[V]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, $|V|$ stands for the degree of the fundamental cycle of $V$ (i.e. the number of points in $V$, counted with appropriate multiplicities), while $\dim_kk[V]$ is the dimension of the $k$-algebra $k[V]$, viewed as a $k$-vector space over $k$. The dimension of an affine variety is $0$ if and only if its coordinate ring is Artinian, in particular of finite dimension over $k$.

Example. $V=Z(x^2)\subset \mathbb A^1_k$ is a double point on the affine line. 
$$2=|V|=\dim_kk[x]/x^2.$$